# How to quickly search through a very large list of strings / records on a text file?

Tags: php

I have some text file size(500mb). I need a script that search given string from this text file as first as possible. i was trying

```
$query="demo";
$FileName = "search.txt";
$fh = fopen($FileName, 'r') or die("Can't open file");
$data = fread($fh, filesize($FileName));
$items = explode(" ", $data);
$Pos = array_search ($query, $items);
if($Pos !== FALSE)
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Is there any script or algorithm to search more faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the fastest tool is `grep`, which is very low-level hand-tuned for exactly this purpose.

Comment: sed will do it too like grep is a command line tool

Comment: @deceze if you don't need regular expressions, [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) may be even faster

Comment: check [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4076694.htm) also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not read the entire file.
Read line by line and check if the `$query` is contained withing the line (assuming the result can't be in multiple lines):

```
$query = 'demo';
$fileName = 'search.txt';
$file = fopen($fileName, 'r') or die("Can't open file");

while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    if (strpos($query, $line) !== false ) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: is there any way to search file without line by line ? cos its very long process. @Darhazer

Comment: Yeah, build an index :) Or use a database, they already support a lot of what you need. In your solution you are reading the entire file then split and search word by word, in my solution you are reading until you actually find the data. Which won't be much faster if the data is in the end of the file. But still will be faster, as won't occupy 500 MB of your memory